# What do I do with the ground wire in a smoke detector install?

Tags: electrical, grounding, smoke-detectors

The electrician ran 14/3 to a metal box.  There is no grounding post on the Kiddie i12010s smoke detector. Can I just cap the ground and call it done?  Doesn’t seem right but I’m not sure how to proceed.
[image: smoke detector]

Comment: What does that red wire connect to on the other side of the 14/3 cable?

Comment: It is a travel wire between units so they all alarm when one does.  It’s not connected to the panel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That looks like a plastic box to me. If it is metal, code requires that the box be grounded. If all the external parts of the smoke detector are plastic then a ground is not required (the same is true with light fixtures).

I don’t usually cap bare grounds. I just tuck them in the box (the entire length is conductive, so I don’t see the point). If it makes you feel better, put a cap on it and tuck it in the box.

Comment: Defiantly plastic. It is blue (where not painted) and has drywall spacing nubs (left side of photo).

Comment: Ok you said metal in the question so I was not sure. But I would just tuck it in the box.

Comment: I guess the point of capping a ground wire could be so it won't find its way into a small hole (e.g. a backstab?)

Comment: I do this professionally and do not use them in 45+ years I have not had a issue. Most electricians do the same it is rare to see a nut on a unused ground. But as I mentioned if it makes you feel better do it.

Comment: Honestly I don't see why it makes any more sense to put a nut on a used ground. I just figured it would be required for this too.

Comment: No it is not required the only time I do anything with unused connectors is usually tape a spare set in the panel to keep them together. A un used red wire in a math room fixture I usually will tape or nut at both ends but that is more a courtesy than a requirement.